# Using Cookies with cURL

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I am logging in remotely to a website using cURL and everything is working fine. I am posting the login information, retrieving the cookies and being redirected by the remote site. I have a few questions about how the cookies are actually functioning.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://website' );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_str);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/php/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/php/cookies.txt');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $x = curl_getinfo($ch);
    print_r($x);
```

1.) Is there some security issues I need to be concerned about by sending the login information via POST?

2.) When I set the `curlopt_cookiejar` to /php/cookies.txt, I don't actually see that file saved anywhere. This may be due to permissions, but the login is working anyways. Why would that be the case? What would be the correct permissions to allow this file to be written to and saved?

3.) Is storing the cookiejar file in plaintext safe? What is the best location to save this file?

4.) If this script is used regularly by multiple users, what is preventing the correct cookie information located in cookies.txt that is sent back to the server using `curlopt_cookiefile` from being mixed up by other cookies that have been written in this file? What is the best way to approach cookies that expire, and removing old cookies from this file?

This is obviously a very important function of cURL, but I can't seem to find these answers anywhere. I'm hoping a cURL master can set these questions straight once and for all to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No

2)
  2.0) It's writing to /php - that is, off the root filesystem, in a folder php. Did you check there? 
  2.1) The cookiejar would only be used for subsequent requests that do NOT post the login information. At this point, I'm wondering what it is you're using the cookiejar for...are you certain you even need these cookies? They (shouldn't) get sent to the third-party site you got redirected to, so what are they doing?
  2.2) The user running PHP (usually the web server) will need write permissions to this file.

3) As long as you put the cookiejar somewhere on your filesystem that others can't get arbitrary access to, you should be fine - for example, you probably want to put it somewhere outside the webroot.

4) If this script is used regularly by multiple users, you'll almost CERTAINLY get a mix of all different kind of data in that file - which indicates that you should probably be giving each user their own cookiejar file, or something...since the location is just set via a PHP string, you shouldn't have too much trouble figuring out how to make it dynamic.  CURL will take care of not writing expired cookies to the jar during subsequent requests and responses.

Comment: 2.0 - I checked there but there are no files that have been written. I think this is due to the folder not having full write permissions. What is the safest way to allow writing? I read so many thing about how CHMOD 777 isn't a good idea..

Comment: 2.1 - The login would only redirect to the correct page if the remote site's cookies were in the header, otherwise it would log me out. 2.2 - can you tell me how to allow write permissions to the server without giving the folder 777 permissions? Is this something I need to do via root access? 3 - can I just use a path like this? /../folder_out_of_webroot/ 4 - Is that to say the cookies.txt file will be automatically be removed when cookies have expired?

Comment: The least-permissive way to grant write permissions to the process that curl will be running as is to get the uid/gid from PHP (via phpinfo()), chown the cookiejar to that user, and then make it 0700 (that's "all rights to the owner, no one else has any rights whatsoever").

Comment: cookies.txt won't be removed - it rewrites the cookies.txt on each request, only putting non-expired cookies in. I would *guess* that if there are no unexpired cookies, it will be a zero byte file, but I'm not certain offhand - there may be some kind of padding left behind.

Comment: You can specify a path to "outside of the webroot" however you want - PHP won't mind, and nothing you do to tell curl where it is located will cause it to suddenly become available inside the webroot.