# GitHub Acces Token POST Error (Cookies required)

Tags: php, cookies, oauth-2.0, access-token, github-api

I got a PHP application, which I am trying to integrate with GitHub. After I get the code from the authentication and I try to exchange it with an access_token I am getting the following error

```
Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub.
```

I am using the cURL library to perform my requests. The headers I set are

- Content-Length: {length}
- Accept: application/json
- User-Agent: my-app

Could help me out with that?

Comment: Try to configure Curl to use cookies ('cookie jar'). You may find the way to achieve this in the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php or on StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126374/using-cookies-with-curl

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Could you share a snippet of the code you're using to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
/* cURL will start a new cookie session and ignore any previous cookies */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
/* this is the name of the file where cURL should save cookie information */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); 
// could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
```